# shrink database or file

Tags: sql-server

Does anyone know the diff between shrink database or file? and what would the pros and cons? in what circumstances you wish to do either one?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, DBCC SHRINKFILE shrinks one file, but DBCC SHRINKDATABASE shrinks all files. This is well documented in Books Online: see the entry for DBCC SHRINKDATABASE. The sections "How DBCC SHRINKDATABASE works" and "Best practices" should answer your questions.

Answer (score 0):

As for some pros/cons, read [this article](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/Auto-shrink-e28093-turn-it-OFF!.aspx) from Paul Randal, and his advice against SHRINKDATABASE.  Just throwing it out there for you.

Comment: nice article but not what i'm after

Comment: btw.. is there a way to fix fragmentation after shrink the database?